# Javascript: overriden methods defined as arrow functions are not seen in parent

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, babeljs

I am using a parent class in my app to provide some basic functionality to its children. It looks roughly like this:

```javascript
class Base {
  constructor(stream) {
    stream.subscribe(this.onData)
  }

  onData(data) {
    throw new Error('"onData" method must be implemented')
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  onData(data) {
    // do stuff...
  }
}
```

That works fine and when I instantiate the `Child`, `Base` passes `Child.onData` to the `stream`
The only problem is scope. In `Child.onData` I make a heavy use of other methods defined in child via `this` keyword. So when I pass this function as a callback to the `stream`, everything breaks. The evident solution is this:

```javascript
class Base {
 constructor(stream) {
   stream.subscribe(this.onData)
 }

 onData = (data) => {
   throw new Error('"onData" method must be implemented')
 }
}

class Child extends Base {
 onData = (data) => {
   // do stuff...
 }
}
```

That does solve problems with scope, but now the function that is being passed to the `stream` is always `Base.onData` which throws errors. Generally, I could do something like passing the `Child.onData` to `Base` constructor. That would work, but what I would like to find is a more elegant solution to this, if it exists

Comment: I am having a hard time following what your issue is...

Comment: It is most likely breaking because you need to bind it when you pass it.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn basically overridden property is not accessible from parent, and I need it to be

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn and I can't bind it before passing, because I can't do anything with `this` before I call the parent constructor

Comment: can you add an example of how you are passing/accessing it

Comment: That's because the child assigns the `this.onData` property *after* the `super()` constructor ran and installed the old, un-overridden value as the stream handler. So a) don't use an arrow function when you plan to override inherited methods b) [don't call (or otherwise use) overridable methods in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404301/1048572).

Comment: You should simply `bind` the method (or use an arrow function wrapper) inside the `Base` constructor

Comment: @Bergi, Ok, I've got the reason of this issue. But I don't pretty much understand, how you suggest to bind it inside `Base` constructor. Could you provide a code snippet please?

Comment: @Bergi, ok, I've got it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why [arrow functions in class properties are not that great](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1). If you translate it to a normal ES6 class, this is what happens:

```
class Child extends Base {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.onData = (data) => {
      // do stuff...
    };
  }
}
```

It's rather evident now why using the property inside the `Base` constructor doesn't work.

Instead, you should use normal method definitions and handle the [context problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) by binding the method inside the parent constructor:

```
class Base {
  constructor(stream) {
    if (this.onData == Base.prototype.onData)
      throw new Error('"onData" method must be overridden')
    this.onData = this.onData.bind(this);
    stream.subscribe(this.onData)
  }

  onData(data) {}
}

class Child extends Base {
  onData(data) {
    // do stuff...
  }
}
```