# Why can't Javascript ES6 call an anonymous super function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, anonymous-function, es6-class

Please explain the difference between using a parent-child relationship using anonymous functions and using class functions? 
In case 1 everything works as expected. In case 2, codepen does not return any results.

```js
//CASE 1
class Parent {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  exec() {
    console.log('name', this.name);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(name, age) {
    super(name);
    this.age = age;
  }

  exec() {
    super.exec();
    console.log('age', this.age);
  }
}

const c = new Child('ChildName', 31);
c.exec();

//writes Childname + 31 (expected behaviour)
```

and

```js
//CASE 2
class Parent {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  exec = () => {
    console.log('name', this.name);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(name, age) {
    super(name);
    this.age = age;
  }

  exec = () => {
    super.exec();
    console.log('age', this.age);
  }
}

const c = new Child('ChildName', 31);
c.exec();

//writes nothing. Seems to crash.
```

Comment: If you're not using a transpiler like babel or something then what you're currently doing is going to fail because class properties ATM cannot be arrow functions. Just hasn't been implemented.

Comment: @kemicofa would throw a SyntaxError though ...

Comment: @kemicofa: i am using babel in my main project. Also using babel on codepen.

Comment: @JonasWilms I am testing this in codepen. The browser does not freeze, but does not produce a result (I assume codepen does not want to compile)

Comment: can you share your codepen?

Comment: @kemicofa my codepen is literally just the 2 cases above.

Comment: Then it has to produce an error.

Comment: @Recipe actually on my screen you never linked it.

Comment: @kemicofa there is no link. I have no account currently on codepen. But if you paste case 1 in there and then case 2 you can see exactly what I am seeing.

Comment: @kemicofa Arrow functions in class properties work just fine, and are implemented in any environment that supports class properties. They just work differently than the OP expected.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Why overriden methods defined as arrow functions are not seen in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57117285/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just one instance object, and there can't be two properties with the same name on one object. Your subclass property overrides the property of the superclass.

Additionally you can't access properties via `super` as `super` refers to the *upper level prototype*, and that does not contain any property in your second case (in your first case it contains the method). Therefore, `super.exec` is `undefined`, and calling that throws an error.

The prototype chains look as follows:

```
 // Case 1
                                              - super ------------v
 { name: "ChildName", age: 31 } -> Child { exec() { ... } } -> Parent { exec() { ... } }


 // Case 2
                                  - super² --------------------v                   
 { name: "ChildName", age: 31, exec() { ... } } -> Child {} -> Parent {}
```

² It might be a bit confusing that `super` inside of the instance points to `Parent`, but that's because class fields are [evaluated inside of a special initializer function](https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/#sec-define-field), and that has `Child` as it's [[HomeObject]], not the instance, and as [`super` refers to the `[[HomeObject]]`s prototype](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-getsuperbase), it will refer to `Parent`.

Comment: Then why is CASE 1 working just fine? 
calling super methods works, but just not with anonymous functions.

Comment: I'm not quite sure on my last statement, I'll reread the relevant spec sections, I'll be back soon

Comment: Update: `super` is lexically resolved, just like `this`, so depending on how the closure gets created for class fields, this *could work*, `super.exec` will still be `undefined` then though.

Comment: Update2: It does actually work. [According to the proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/#runtime-semantics-class-field-definition-evaluation) the initializer gets executed inside of a function that behaves exactly like the constructor(), so both `this`and `super` can be accessed. Won't work still.