# How to invoke arrow functions on a superclass with `super` in subclass

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6, super

It seems you cannot call a superclass arrow function using `super.methodName()` within a subclass:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('in `Parent` constructor')
  }
  parentArrow = () => {
    console.log('parentArrowFn')
  }
  parentMethod() {
    console.log('parentMethod')
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log('in `Child` constructor')
  }
  childMethod() {
    console.log('childMethod')
    super.parentMethod() // works
    super.parentArrow() // Error
  }
}

(new Child()).childMethod();
```

Generates the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).parentArrow is not a function
    at Child.childMethod (<anonymous>:21:15)
    at <anonymous>:1:7
```

#### Is there any way to prevent this so that I can use arrow functions in my parent class, yet ensure they are accessible via `super` in subclasses?

Comment: Do you have to use `super` or is `this` also an option? (It works with `this`)

Comment: Why do you need `super` here? Both of these examples work properly if you use `this.` instead.

Comment: Also, it's unusual to use arrow functions for methods, because they won't be able to use `this`.

Comment: @KevinB I'm don't know about that. If it was and that has been sufficiently answered, maybe mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: @Barmar I use arrow functions with transform-class-properties plugin to avoid having to bind methods in constructor in react classes. I thought this was pretty common, no?

Comment: @Barmar I agree https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559267/why-cant-javascript-es6-call-an-anonymous-super-function seems similar, but there aren't better answers there.

Comment: You think the answers here are better? I could reverse the duplicate link.

Comment: @barmar wrong! `this` points to the instance inside arrow functions inside class fields. (but good dupe ;))

Comment: @1252748 the only answer here is technically wrong ...

Comment: To answer your question: You just cannot. You cannot refer to properties of the instance via `super`. Also you can't have two properties with the same name

Comment: @JonasWilms Are "class fields" something new and special? I was just talking about ordinary object properties. Arrow functions don't get their context from the call site, they get it from the definition site.

Comment: @barmar yes, "class fields" are a stage 3 proposal. `class Test { field = value }` is roughly equal  to `class Test { constructor() { this._init(); } _init() { this.field = value }}`, so in other words: (1) initialized before the constructors body gets run, (2) `this`and `super` work the way they would in a regular method, just that arrow functions initialized there get bound

Answer (score 4):

Public fields or "class instance fields" in es6 classes are not yet supported natively in all environments and even if it is you need to call it through a `this` reference instead of `super` as it becomes an *instance* property rather than a property on the *prototype*:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('in `Parent` constructor')
  }   
  parentArrow = () => {
      console.log('parentArrowFn')
  }
  parentMethod() {
    console.log('parentMethod')
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log('in `Child` constructor')
  }
  childMethod() {
    console.log('childMethod')
    super.parentMethod() // works
    this.parentArrow() // Calls parentArrow 
  } 
}
new Child().childMethod();
```

The need to call the arrow function using `this` instead of `super` is because when using an arrow function as a method the `parentArrow` is added as a property of the *instance* rather than of the *prototype* and `super` is used for calling methods declared on the prototype.

Your code can be translated to the code below, when you declare an arrow function inside a class:

```
constructor() {
   console.log('in `Parent` constructor');
   // becomes an instance property
   this.parentArrow = () => { <----
     console.log('parentArrowFn') |
   }                              |
}                                 |
parentArrow = () => {          ----
   console.log('parentArrowFn')
}
```

Comment: *as the parentArrow property is not defined until the Child constructor is not finished completely.* wrong! According to the proposal, class fields are run before the code in the constructor runs. Also this is not a timing issue, as childMethod is called after construction was finished

Comment: @JonasWilms rephrased and corrected my answer.